# Lock out edit and destroy Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a review model that I would like to lock out the edit and destroy button after 30 minutes and if only the correct user. Right now I just have an if statement around the button but you can still get to it by putting in the full URL. Where/ how would I go about doing this? I am new to Ruby on Rails and any help is useful. Thanks in advance!

Edit: All I have is below in the index but the problem is that I can still get to it through the URL and I don't know how to make those inaccessible after that.

```
<% if signed_in? %>
          <% if current_user.id = review.user_id %>
            <% if !review.has_time_passed? %>
              <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_property_review_path(review.property,   review) %></td>
                <% if !review.comments.any? %>
                  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [review.property, review], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

My has_time_passed method:

```
def has_time_passed?
    created_at < 30.minutes.ago
  end
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you've done in trying to achieve this?

Comment: I saw your post title and thought "why does this person hate Ruby on Rails?"

Comment: Is there a way I can do this all through the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least 2 pieces to what I think you're describing:

1. You need to ensure the view template hides any edit and destroy links after 30 minutes.
2. You need to add logic to the relevant controller actions (`edit` and `destroy`) to ensure they'll refuse to make any changes after 30 minutes.

As far as the view logic goes, it sounds like you're pretty close and this shouldn't be too difficult. One `if` statement phrasing that comes to mind (similar to what you pasted above, but a tiny bit simpler):

```
if review.created_at <= 30.minutes.ago
```

Then, in the controller, you'll also want to ensure the action only makes changes within the time limit. So for example you might use the same if statement:

```
def edit
  if review.created_at <= 30.minutes.ago
    redirect_to some_other_path, alert: "Sorry bro, this review is too old to be edited."
  else
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

That's just a very rough-draft example. Once you have everything working, *then* extract the logic into a method on the model (to reduce redundancy) and so forth.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! I think you can still mark as accepted answer even if you can't vote.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to introduce an authorization framework like [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

That way you separate the logic that interacts with the model from the controller, for which it's a good idea to keep it as minimalistic as possible.

Both Pundit and CanCan have great tutorials that show how to achieve similar scenarios to what you are trying to achieve.

In Pundit, for example, your policy would like somewhat like this:

```
class MyModelPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :my_model

  def initialize(user, model)
    @user = user
    @my_model = model
  end

  def destroy?
    user == my_model.user && my_model.created_at < 30.minutes.ago
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something at the controller level.

```
# app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
class ReviewsController
  before_action :validate_change, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
    # edit stuff
  end

  def destroy
    # destroy stuff
  end

  private

  def validate_change
    if @review.created_at < 30.minutes.ago
      redirect_to request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
    end
  end
end
```